# how to write a java stored procedure?

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

How to write a java stored procedure in oracle?
What are the advantages of java stored procedures over pl/sql stored procedures?

Thanks

Comment: I would imagine they are easier to code... Java being an easier language to learn.

Comment: It makes it easier to muck up your database

Comment: djangofan, lol, I would imagine you're taking the mickey...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search turns up a page on using Java Stored Procedures written by [Oracle themselves](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should really have googled this. 
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chfive.htm